# Visual Studio 2008 Setup Project is not generating Setup.exe anymore

Tags: visual-studio, installation, setup.exe

I have a Visual Studio 2008 Setup Project that when compiled in the past would generate a Setup.exe in the output directory along with the .msi output file. Now it no longer generates the Setup.exe which I actually do need.

Did I change a project setting without realizing? How do I get it to generate it again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try opening project properties, click Prerequisites button there and check "Create setup program to install prerequisite components".

This is for Visual Studio 2005, not sure if it works for Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 2):

1, Go to file menu > click Add > new project >now “Add New Project” Dialog appear.

2.Select “Other Project Types” and click “Setup and Deployment” projects,Choose “Setup Project”give name project name in name text box finally click OK.

3.New project appear in solution explorer,for example you give the name “MyEXE”..it will display with this name.

4.right click the MyEXE > go View > click “File System”

5.You can see the “File System on TargetMachine”under  three folders
Application Folder
User’s Desktop
User’s Program Menu

6.Select Application Folder and right click Add>Project Output>select Primary output

7. select User’s Desktop richt click on the second window>click create new shortcut>select output file from Application folder>change the file name from  primary output name to MyEXE

next >>

same procedure follows the user’s program menu also

8.If you want to change the Manufactures name for exe,just right click the project go to properties

change the properties as per you requirement

9.Finally Build the new project After successfully Build the project myEXE(Setup) will be appear in Application Debug or Release folder(depend upon the properties settings)

EXE available @ this location

When you want to install  the EXE on the client machine,you should be installed .NET Framework on that mc because,Applications and controls written for the .NET Framework version 2.0 require the .NET Framework Redistributable Package version 2.0 to be installed on the computer where the application or control runs.